# How to combine a normal list with a nested list in python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list and a nested list in python that I want to combine. An example of the problem is below:

```
list_1 = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]],[[19,20,21],
         [22,23,24],[25,26,27]]]
list_2 = ['23.43', '24.56', '25.78']
```

I want to combine the two list so I get the following result:

```
result = [['23.43',[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],['24.56',[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]],
          ['25.78',[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27]]]
```

I tried the following:

```
result = map(list.__add__, list_2, list_1)
```

But i got the following error:

```
TypeError: descriptor '__add__' requires a 'list' object but received a 'float'
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for, although you may have to modify it a bit to get it how you want your data:

```
   result = zip(list_1,list_2)
```